# How to get weighted average grouped by a column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a model `Company` that have columns `pbr`, `market_cap` and `category`.

To get averages of `pbr` grouped by `category`, I can use `group` method.

```
Company.group(:category).average(:pbr)
```

But there is no method for weighted average.

To get weighted averages I need to run this SQL code.

```
select case when sum(market_cap) = 0 then 0 else sum(pbr * market_cap) / sum(market_cap) end as weighted_average_pbr, category AS category FROM "companies" GROUP BY "companies"."category";
```

In `psql` this query works fine. But I don't know how to use from Rails.

```
sql = %q(select case when sum(market_cap) = 0 then 0 else sum(pbr * market_cap) / sum(market_cap) end as weighted_average_pbr, category AS category FROM "companies" GROUP BY "companies"."category";)
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql)
```

returns a error:

```
 output error: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `keys' for #<Array:0x007ff441efa618>>
```

It would be best if I can extend Rails method so that I can use

```
Company.group(:category).weighted_average(:pbr)
```

But I heard that extending rails query is a bit tweaky, now I just want to know how to run the result of sql from Rails.

Does anyone knows how to do it?

#### Version

rails: 4.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Rails are you using? I don't get that error with Rails 4.2. In Rails 3.2 [`select_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements/select_all) used to return an `Array`, and [in 4.2](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements/select_all) it returns an `ActiveRecord::Result`. But in either case, it is correct that there is no `keys` method. Instead you need to call `keys` on each element of the `Array` or `Result`. It sounds like the problem isn't from running the query, but from what you're doing afterward.

In any case, to get the more fluent approach you've described, you could do this:

```
class Company
  scope :weighted_average, lambda{|col|
    select("companies.category").
    select(<<-EOQ)
      (CASE WHEN SUM(market_cap) = 0 THEN 0
            ELSE SUM(#{col} * market_cap) / SUM(market_cap)
       END) AS weighted_average_#{col}
    EOQ
  }
```

This will let you say `Company.group(:category).weighted_average(:pbr)`, and you will get a collection of `Company` instances. Each one will have an extra `weighted_average_pbr` attribute, so you can do this:

```
Company.group(:category).weighted_average(:pbr).each do |c|
  puts c.weighted_average_pbr
end
```

These instances will *not* have their normal attributes, but they will have `category`. That is because they do not represent individual Companies, but groups of companies with the same `category`. If you want to group by something else, you could parameterize the lambda to take the grouping column. In that case you might as well move the `group` call into the lambda too.

Now **be warned** that the parameter to `weighted_average` goes straight into your SQL query without escaping, since it is a column name. So make sure you don't pass user input to that method, or you'll have a SQL injection vulnerability. In fact I would probably put a guard inside the lambda, something like `raise "NOPE" unless col =~ %r{\A[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\Z}`.

The more general lesson is that you can use `select` to include extra SQL expressions, and have Rails magically treat those as attributes on the instances returned from the query.

Also note that unlike with `select_all` where you get a bunch of hashes, with this approach you get a bunch of `Company` instances. So again there is no `keys` method! :-)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the when I run `Company.group(:category).weighted_average(:pbr)` it returns `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "companies.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` error... I'm using rails `4.2.1`.

Comment: Ah of course---sorry! That is because I need to select just `category`, not `*`. Edited the answer with that change plus some explanation about it.